# Laravel - How to resolve Argument 2 passed to with() must be callable or null, object given

Tags: laravel

I have this code in my Laravel-5.8

Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    if (! Gate::allows('appraisal_goal_edit')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id','appraisal_name')->where('company_id', 
    $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first(); 
    $employees = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('id', $userEmployee)->first();
    $goal           =       AppraisalGoal::findOrFail($id);
    $goaltypes      =       AppraisalGoalType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get(); 
    $goaldetails    =       AppraisalGoalDetail::where('appraisal_goal_id', $id)->get();

    $appraisalgoaltype = DB::table('appraisal_goals')->select('goal_type_id')->where('id', $id)->first()->goal_type_id;
    // appraisal score
    $scoreidentities  = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first()->id;      
    $child  = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id',$appraisalgoaltype)->first();      
    $parentid  = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('parent_id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id',$appraisalgoaltype)->first()->parent_id;

   if(empty($child))
   {
       abort(404);
   }  
   $weightedscore = 0;
   $weightedscore = DB::table('appraisal_goals')->select(DB::raw("IFNULL(SUM(weighted_score),0) as weighted_score"))->where('appraisal_identity_id', $scoreidentities)->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('parent_id', $parentid)->first();
   $maxscore = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('max_score')->find($child->parent_id);
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.edit')
            ->with('goaltypes', $goaltypes)
            ->with('goal', $goal)
            ->with('goaldetails', $goaldetails)
            ->with('categories', $categories)
            ->with('identities', $identities)
            >with('weightedscore', $weightedscore)
            ->with('maxscore', $maxscore)
            ->with('employees', $employees);
}
```

View

```
          <input type="hidden" id="max_score" value="{{$maxscore->max_score}} class="form-control" >
            <input type="hidden" id="weighted_score" value="{{$weightedscore->weighted_score}} class="form-control" >
```

When I run the code, I got this error:

> Argument 2 passed to with() must be callable or null, object given

I discovered that the error is on this line:

```
            >with('weightedscore', $weightedscore)
            ->with('maxscore', $maxscore)
```

When I did:

> die(var_dump($weightedscore));

I got:

> object(stdClass)#2494 (1) { ["weighted_score"]=> string(2) "40" }

and when I did:

> die(var_dump($maxscore));

I got:

> object(stdClass)#2516 (1) { ["max_score"]=> int(75) }

How do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You are missing a dash in the first error line: `->with('weightedscore', $weightedscore)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting in the missing dash for this line here

```php
   ->with('identities', $identities)
// ↓ here
    >with('weightedscore', $weightedscore)
   ->with('maxscore', $maxscore)
```

helps to solve this issue.